# Can't I set a variable as a textbox value

Tags: php, html, web

```
$value = 3;
<input type="number" name="rowid" value=$value readOnly><br>
```

I tried setting a variable as textbox value, however,it won't work. Is it impossible to set a variable as a textbox value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the variable

```
<input type="number" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" readOnly><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

echo `$value` inside `value=""`

```
$value = 3;
<input type="number" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $value;?>" readOnly><br>
```

OR

```
<input type="number" name="rowid" value="<?= $value;?>" readOnly><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just placing the value `$value` there. It doesn't have any sense to have `$value` without opening php tag there.

You need to echo the `$value` to have assign on `rowid`.

You should do

`<input type="number" name="rowid" value="<?= $value ?>" readOnly><br>`

or

`<input type="number" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $value ?>" readOnly><br>`

**Additional Tip :**

You can do the debug yourself by seeing the Page's source `(view-source://yourpagename.php)` or by Inspecting the area where you starring in from the Browser

Comment: The asp style tags (`<? ... ?>`) is not always enabled. Why not use `<?= $value ?>` instead?

Comment: @HasseBjörk Agree and Updated Friend :)